# Why does [x] * n use less memory then [x for _ in range(n)] in Python?

Tags: python, memory

I was comparing speed, and memory usage of different data structures in Python3.8.

When comparing 2 methods for making lists I found they used up a different amount of memory.

```
import sys

x = 0
n = 100
method1 = [x for _ in range(n)]
method2 = [x] * n

print(sys.getsizeof(method1))
print(sys.getsizeof(method2))

# Output:
904
856
```

I didn't understand why this was the case so I tried the following things (using 'methody' as an example):

- printing the lists. `print(methody)`
- printing their lengths.`print(len(methody))`
- replacing x with another value. `x = 30` `x = 'a'`
- replacing n with another value. `n = 5` `n = 1000`
- replacing certain values. `methody[2] = 'a'` -> `print(methody)`

They both gave the same results each time so I'm still confused.

Can someone explain this memory difference?

Comment: Lists can have excess capacity, to be able to handle inserts & appends without having to reallocate the entire memory of the list each time.  The exact amount of this excess capacity a list has depends on the full history of how the list got to its current size; it's not really predictable, but in general things that specify an explicit size will result in less excess capacity.

Comment: Interesting question. You can also try `list(x for _ in range(n))` which gives you yet another number (at least here, on my machine).